# Excel 2010 - Data Validation not accepting the decimal "0"

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a range in my spreadsheet with custom type formatting:

```
##":"##
```

on the range I have also setup data validation:

**Validation criteria**

```
Allow: Text length (Ignore blank is unchecked)
Data: equal to
Length: 4
```

because I want to make sure that users use 4 decimals when typing, for instance 1300 or 0925.

**Problem:**

If the user input begins with "0", for instance 0900 the validation criteria fails. Why is that? Am I missing something crucial?

Thanks.

Comment: Try changing your custom formatting to 00":"00 Your version omits leading zeroes which is the problem i think. 0#":"## might be what you need exactly...but the other one should work too.

Comment: With 00":"00 typing 0900 still gives validation error and 0##":"## doesnt seem to work since it prefixes everything, for instance 1300 becomes 013:00

Comment: Ok, it might not fix your underlying problem then. But you got a typo in the one that gives you 013:00, it is a # too many. # means a digit except if it is a leading zero. 0 means a digit regardless.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I just tried 0#":"## and the validation error still occur.

Comment: You want the length of the entered text (if the field is a text field it will return length 4 for 0900) but you want to use the number format which requires a number. But 0900 as a number turns into 900 so length is not 4. I suppose you need something more complex to address this special situation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did the VBA to convert number to time value not work for you? Why do you want to format the cell at all? We've discussed the shortcomings of the formatting approach in your other question.

Excel ignores leading zeros when you enter a number. Therefor your data validation for 4 digits will never fly. The only way to retain a leading zero is to enter it as text. But when you enter text, you cannot use a format to format the text to show as `00:00`.

Back to square one. You need VBA for this. I've provided a [perfectly working function](https://superuser.com/questions/609031/excel-convert-number-entry-into-time-value/609050#609050) in your other question.

Simply formatting does not cut it. You need VBA.

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly, I'm just playing around with different solutions :). Call it curiousity, I'm still fairly new to Excel and VBA.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of custom formatting, format cells to 'text'

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in this case, the question author wants to use custom formatting, but they're trying to fix their format. (Also, welcome to Super User - for an intro, see the [tour]!)